# Great Stuff Foam sealed gas pipe, fire safety

Tags: insulation, pipe, natural-gas

So I have a pipe penetration problem at the gas pipe. I hired a contractor and he decided to use great stuff to seal the gap. Would it be a fire safety problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Code may say something about this, so just a comment: If you have a fire safety problem due to the foam being flammable **around a gas pipe** then I think you have bigger problems - i.e., why is there a fire near a gas pipe in the first place?

Comment: What is this pipe penetrating through?

Comment: That's a [really good question](https://www.neimagazine.com/features/featureremembering-the-browns-ferry-fire-40-years-on-4578707/).

Comment: Depends on the color of the foam... Great stuff does make foam for fire blocking and it is a orangey red color. If it is not red, then it is no good

Comment: Although I agree with @gunner. I have not been required to use fire blocking in a residential setting. with the exception of going from a garage to a living space.+

Comment: The stuff that Great stuff offers that is orangish-red is identical to the same regular spray foam. It is colored for easy identification for inspectors to see where the fire blocking is. How either is rated to heat I can't say.

Comment: The question is more about "is this a fire-rated wall?" than "what kind of service passes through the penetration?" If the wall isn't required to be fire-rated in the first place then the kind of insulation doesn't matter. If it is required to be fire-rated, then the AHJ may have an opinion about whether the great stuff foam is acceptable. It wouldn't matter whether the penetration was for gas, water, electricity, data/low voltage, central vacuum, etc.

Comment: Correct. The only issue is whether or not the wall is fire rated or not, and in residences, that is usually only the wall separating an attached garage and the rest of the house.  The "Fire Rated" foam filler is different in that it is "intumescent", a term meaning that when fire hits it, it chars and expands, robbing the fire of further fuel to penetrate (for a specific amount of time). If you have ever played with the "snake" fireworks, that is a perfect example of an intumescent material. The orange color signifies that the material is rated as a fire stop material.